# How to apply Ext.Net V2 Combobox control on Html Input control with Combobox Applyto property?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, extjs4, ext.net

I am trying to apply ext.net V2 combobox on HTML Input control Dynamicly. Its work fine in ext.net V1 but not working with V 2.

```
new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                                editable: false,
                                store: storeGender,
                                listeners: {
                                    select: function () {
                                        if (this.oldValue == this.value) {
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                        UpdateValues(this.getEl().id, this.value,(_rows - 9));
                                        this.container.addCls('x-grid-dirty-cell');
                                    }
                                },
                                displayField: 'text',
                                valueField: 'value',
                                typeAhead: true,
                                queryMode: 'local',
                                forceSelection: true,
                                triggerAction: 'all',
                                selectOnFocus: true,
                                width: 80,
                                applyTo: 'ctl_' + i + '_' + j
                            });
```

This issue arrise when upgread my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ext.NET 2 uses ExtJS 4.1 which dropped the support for applyTo and removed it from most components, for a combobox try the configuration property "**[transform](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-transform)**" which does almost the same thing ,check the below links for more info:

[applyTo non exist ??](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?124801-applyTo-non-exist)

[add applyTo to Ext 4.1](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?158065-add-applyTo-to-Ext-4.1)

Comment: "transform" works from V1.1 and it recreate that control and change ID ... But I dont want to change ID. Because I use that in code.

Comment: @user2666817 Then try and apply the fix to add **applyTo** as described in the second link